# An invalid value was provided for the parameter 'deviceNumber' while registering multiple devices

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I did it before, i.e., registered multiple devices (iPads) just by uploading a text file containing UDIDs and names, and it worked fine, but today I get this error: "An invalid value was provided for the parameter 'deviceNumber'".
I have 70 empty slots, and am trying to add 10 devices.

What is device number? There is no such a thing in the sample files they provide, just device id and name.

Comment: Mb you have duplicate device. Try to add 5 and 5 devices.

Comment: nope, i just added them manually one by one, they all went in w/o problems.

Comment: In my case I was trying to register an iphone device under Mac Apps selected at the top left.

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 post as an answer for some badges man!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug/incorrect example in Apple's importing mechanism.

Today I tried to import my devices in a plist file (example was brought from the developer center, "Download sample files" link, `multiple-device-upload-ios.deviceids` file) and got the same error.

To eliminate worries about duplicates/malformed plist, I simplified the plist to contain only 1 device, uploaded it, the error remained the same.

The solution was to use a file format as described in `multiple-device-upload-ios.txt` file:

```
Device ID   Device Name
A123456789012345678901234567890123456789    NAME1
B123456789012345678901234567890123456789    NAME2
```

Worked like a charm.

P.S.: Notice the ***tabs*** between `Device ID` and `Device Name` and between actual numbers and a names. In a name, you may use whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem when I edit the file in texteditor. I edited the file in xcode and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by transforming device IDs to uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, if you are using Notepad, it probably would insert all kinds of hidden characters, etc., that would result in this error. Solved the problem by copying and pasting into Wordpad and deleting some unnecessary whitespaces (and also putting all device IDs in uppercase).